# Fetching the certificate fingerprint if an apk is signed with only v2 Signing Scheme

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-app-signing, apksigner, apk-signing

The v2 signing scheme works (referred in the link) [v2 Signing Scheme](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2)
I have few doubts regarding the same.

If an apk is ***only*** signed with v2 signing scheme (not by v1 signing scheme) then, how to fetch the certificate fingerprint of an apk? The problem is there is no (CERT.RSA) file over there.

I tried searching a lot over the internet but everywhere solution is given w.r.t when v1 signing scheme is used.
Which existing tool can be used to extract APK Signing block?

Answer (score 4):

**Apksigner** is the tool to use:

```
apksigner verify --print-certs -verbose app.apk
```

apksigner is shipped with the Android SDK Build Tools.